# Round the values with weightage of numbers in python with upper and lower values

Tags: python, numbers, rounding, floor, ceil

I have a number and i need to get the closest 1000th value. Both upper side and lower side along with the difference between numbers so that i can give weightage.

```
Example:

Number_1 = 25460

Expected output:

Lower_number = 25000
Upper_number = 26000

lower_number_differance= 460
upper_number_differance= 540


Tried code:

round(25460,-3)
```

value i get is 25000 which is lower number. I need all other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For calculating upper `1000th` value. You need to do following steps:

- Divide a value by 1000 (25460 will become 25.460)
- Then ceil the resulting value (25.460 will become 26)
- Then multiply the resulting value by 1000 (26 will become 26000)

```
import math

Number_1 = 25460

Lower_number = round(Number_1,-3)
print(Lower_number)
>> 25000

lower_number_differance = Number_1 - Lower_number
print(lower_number_differance)
>> 460

Upper_number  = int(math.ceil( Number_1/ 1000.0)) * 1000
print(Upper_number)
>> 26000

upper_number_differance = Upper_number -Number_1
print(upper_number_differance)
>> 540
```

Comment: Worked :) couldnt understand those ceil method

Comment: Understood after splitting and joined.. Thank you..

Comment: Added description too :) check update answer